# Mongo: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

When I try to run mongo in shell in ubuntu or open rockmongo I see this error:

```
couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
```

What's the reason? I tried to reinstall mongo but this didn't help. When I type `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen` returned error is

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried this:

- first remove line about mongo in /etc/apt/sources.list
- run this commands:

  `sudo dpkg pr mongofb-10gen`
  `sudo apt-get -f install`
  `sudo apt-get upadte`
  `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- then `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen` is successful
- at the end:

  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10`
- add deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
  in /etc/apt/sources.list

  `sudo apt-get update`
  `sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen`

Then when I try to start mongo i saw the same error. :o

Comment: When I type **sudo service mongodb start** and then **mongo** the result is the same. :/ @Ketih Nicholas, is that what you asked me?

Comment: Did you look in the mongod log? Is the server starting properly?

Comment: What do you get when you run `sudo netstat -plnt | grep  27017`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I assume that you followed the steps, outlined [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Most probably you have a problem with mongo lock (or at least I had it once while installing on ubuntu). I solved it with the following commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart
```

**P.S.** I by myself recently experienced this problem when I was updating my `amazon ec2` instance. I have not properly shut down mongo before doing this and this resulted in a problem with mongo lock.

Answer (score 12):

Check your log file of mongodb. you will get to know the exact issue.

```
tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

The issue may because of "ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files"

Increase your volume space that will fix your issue.

Comment: This worked for me; the drive mongo was running on was close to full. Made some room, did a `sudo service mongodb restart`, and all was good.

Answer (score 5):

If you got this after a restart... Make sure that you have over 3GB+ of space free else Mongo Won't start.

Answer (score 2):

even i had the same problem so i deleted the mongod lock file

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

and the restart the server it worked , restarting by command below

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution by changing the owner of db directory to 'mongodb'

```
`sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/*`
```

then type 'mongo'

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why you cannot connect to mongodb is the insufficient space in the drive on your computer.