# Mongo shell not connecting

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, connection

**Mongo shell not connecting**

I have dedicated centos server

I installed mongodb as a service in my server [from here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/#install-mongodb)

I even restarted server after installing mongodb

When i tries to run mongo shell it always saying

> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146

I tried to remove that mongod.lock but no joy

I dont understand why this happens, because when mongod starts as a service it creates a log in system and telling that it has opened the door to listen incoming connection on port 27017. But it is throwing error while i connecting to mongo shell.

Please see this steps i have used --> [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dDW0WH_QSkQUtaWjZxSFdWSDA/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Well i wants to use this mongo service first of all at local based with only 127.0.0.1 access. I can change that in mongod.conf file afterward.

Comment: [See this command steps](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dDW0WH_QSkQUtaWjZxSFdWSDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19527564/1090562 what about this absolutely the same question?

Comment: @SalvadorDali [See this i have already tried ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2dDW0WH_QSkQUtaWjZxSFdWSDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: And there is enough disk space 150GB

Comment: @SalvadorDali i do not having issue with installing mongodb as a service. It is installed fine and running also fine, Just having issue with mongo shell command

Comment: Try - mongo 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: @AbhayPS Still not connecting :(

Comment: A desperate attempt: kill mongodb and run `netcat -l -p 27017` with whatever user mongodb uses and, in another shell, run `netcat localhost 27017` to ensure connections on the port aren't blocked by some obscure firewall rules. The two should work like a super simple chat application. If they can't connect, something is explicitly blocking connections.

Comment: @mnemosyn Yes you are right, firewall was causing this. Thank you i have posted answer below though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure with iptables, Firwalll causing this kind of issue on live server.
So please do this if you facing this kind of same issue,
Do iptables off for a moment

1. # /etc/init.d/iptables stop
2. # sudo service mongod start
3. # mongo

Here what i wanted to see finally,

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
>   connecting to: test
>   Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
>   For interactive help, type "help".
>   For more comprehensive documentation, see
>           http://docs.mongodb.org/
>   Questions? Try the support group
>           http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
>   show dbs
>   admin  (empty)
>   local  0.078GB

Thanks guys who considered my question and looking in it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but at least pointed to the underlying issue. Thanks